# Bubble Sort an Array

Tags: java

I have an add point method, which adds a slot and puts a point inside. After adding the slot I want to sort what is in the array. How do I do that? Here is my code:

```
public void add(Point p) 
{
    int k;
    for (int j = 0;j<myConsumerCurve.length;j++)

    for (k=j+1;k<myConsumerCurve.length;k++)

    if (k!=j && myConsumerCurve[k] == myConsumerCurve[j]) {
    }

    Point[] tempCurve = new Point [myConsumerCurve.length +1];

    for(int i=0; i < myConsumerCurve.length; i++)
    {
        tempCurve[i] = myConsumerCurve[i];
    }

    tempCurve[myConsumerCurve.length] = p;

    myConsumerCurve = tempCurve;

    bubblesort(myConsumerCurve);
}

   public static void bubblesort(Point[] myConsumerCurve)
{


}
```

Comment: Assuming that the array is already sorted, you could utilise a binary search approach to find the best point at which the element should be added.  You could also use `Arrays.binarySearch` and/or `Arrays.sort` to make life easier. Of course, if you want to do it yourself, you could check out the multitude of examples on [google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=java+bubble+sort&oq=java+bubble+sort&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2863j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @MadProgrammer So would this be correct?:

    Arrays.sort(myConsumerCurve);

Comment: [Everything you ever wanted to know about the bubble sort. Aka- Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

Comment: @retrogirl19 Something like would work, you'd need to verify that's in the order you expect it and that the objects you are trying to sort are `Comparable`, otherwise you will need to provide your own `Comparator`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Right, thank you so much!